# notify-send with crontab in i3

Tags: ubuntu, cron, i3, notifications, notify-send

I am trying to create a cron job that sends a notification via notify-send.

I am currently trying this:

```
*/2 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus /usr/bin/notify-send "test"
```

which is working if I just run it from a terminal.

I've also tried setting

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/munhunger/.Xauthority
```

I have a similar crontab that runs a shell script with the same variables that is printing to a log file, so I know that the crontab is working. But still, no notifications are showing up.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be wrong?

I am running with Ubuntu 17.10 with i3 on top

Comment: Set `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` as well. And check your `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` for a valid value.

Comment: my `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` seems to be valid... never seen the `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` before. Do you have any suggestion as to what to set it to?

Comment: my `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-idumFnhFQ6,guid=484c45028754af8abc0cbc995b72642b'`. Are you sure you have more simple value?

Comment: Well, I am not entirely sure. but running `printenv` my `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` looks like that

Answer (score 5):

I run i3 on Ubuntu 18.04. This is how I solve it:

`* * * * *  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "this is dog!"`

Comment: I tried dozens of suggestions to fix this issue and this is the only one that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me out as well. I opted to export this variable in the shell script I'm running, to keep my crontab clean.